# TypeError: callback.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a bit new to node and mongoose, I'm trying to delete all the documents in a collection. I am using this code:

```
app.delete('/accounts', function deleteAccount(req, res, next){

    Account.remove({}, {multi:true});
    res.json({
        message: 'Accounts Deleted!'
    });

});
```

The issue is when I make an API request to this method, it starts processing and doesn't stop, unless I abort it. The code removes all the documents in my collection, but it is doing it with an error.  This is the error it throws:

> events.js:141
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> TypeError: callback.apply is not a function

I want my code to work without this error and I don't want my request to hang while it is processing a requst. Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a callback for `remove` method :

```
Account.remove({}, function(err, result){
  res.json({
        message: 'Accounts Deleted!'
    });
});
```

And if you don't want to wait for completing :

```
var cmd = Account.remove({});
cmd.exec();
res.json({
            message: 'Accounts Deleted!'
        });
```

Actually `remove` gets two arguments which the second one in optional.
If the second one is present it should be a callback.

In removing documents you don't have `multi` option.

The exception you get is that exactly for mongoose consider `{multi: true}` as a callback